# CSOM PowerShell - $folder -PropertyName "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I'm trying to use the [Load-CSOMProperties.ps1](https://gist.github.com/glapointe/cc75574a1d4a225f401b#file-load-csomproperties-ps1) made by Gary Lapointe to report me if a folder "HasUniqueRoleAssignments". This is working fine for webs and lists but it doesn't seem to work for folders.

> Load-CSOMProperties : Instance property 'HasUniqueRoleAssignments' is
>   not defined for type  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder At
>   E:\OneDrive\Powershell\CSOM\DoStuff.ps1:108 char:9
>   +         Load-CSOMProperties -object $folder -propertyNames @("HasUniq ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Load-CSOMProperties

Anyone has an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the folders "item" before making the call.
E.g.

```
$ctx.Load($folder)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$item = $folder.ListItemAllFields;
Load-CSOMProperties -object $item -propertyNames @("HasUniqueRoleAssignments");
```

Also note that the same is true for Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File
Call the ListItemAllFields property same as with a folder.